# Memory management with block and ARC, leak?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I need to know if I do it correctly. The application is running OK but I'm not sure I get the lifecycle correctly (leak ?).

Note: Instrument see no leak.

The code of a method aaa: of some class A:

```
- (void) aaa {
   NSString *path = ...something...;

   NSBlockOperation* theOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
   // using path
   [self somethingElseWith:path];
   }];

   [self.aQueue addOperation:theOp];
}
```

So I create a block to put on aQueue (NSOperationQueue*). The goal is to offload from the main thread the long running somethingElseWith: method, so that the GUI continue to be responsive.

Inside the block I reference the local var "path" that will be out of scope at the end of the aaa: method.

If I read the doc correctly, the block will do a retain on 'path'. But is ARC inserting a release at the end of this block implicitly ? Would be logical and nice.

Or should I declare 'path' as __block and assign it to nil at the end of my block ? (manual...)

Not sure I understand how to use __weak in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `path` variable is fine. You may however need to avoid a retain cycle by using a `weak` reference to `self`. If `aQueue` is a `strong` reference there may be a retain cycle causing `self` never to be released.

Solution:

```
- (void) aaa {
   NSString *path = ...something...;

   __weak id self_ = self;
   NSBlockOperation* theOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
   // using path
   [self_ somethingElseWith:path];
   }];

   [self.aQueue addOperation:theOp];
}
```

*Make sure the operation does not get called after the class should no longer exist.*

Comment: Thanks. Question: if ARC was not used, is the `path` variable fine also ? Or in need of a `[path release]` at the end of the block ?

Comment: @malaba the path variable is fine with or without ARC since the block will retain path for you and release it when the block is deallocated/out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

The block will automatically handle memory management for any locals from the enclosing scope. You don't have to worry about retain/release pairs in this case. Note, though that `path` will be `const` within the block's scope.  If you need `path`to be mutable within the block, use the `__block` attribute.

The different ways a block handles variables is described in detail [here: Blocks and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1)